# Earse painting using PorterDuffXfermode with transparent color

Tags: android, paint

I am doing finger paint app.In that i need earse functionality for drawn paths.Every thing is working fine by using

```
 PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
```

The only thing is it showing black color while it earsing.Is it possible to change it to some transparent color.

Comment: you can try mpaint.setColor(Color.WHITE). This will paint white color on the draw. if you have a image as a background with blue color. if you try erasing , white is drawn over the blue. This works if the entire image background is white

Comment: i have image as background with different colors

Comment: then the above won't work.